# Text topic classification in tensorflow

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow, cnn

I want to create a `CNN` in `tensorflow` that does the following:
Classify a recipe headline and find out the topic. For instance `super yummy cheesy cake` should result in `cheese cake` and so on.

I thought for going with `tensorflow`, but need some help in getting things started.

### My strategy is like that:

1. Normalize the headlines so `cheesy` becomes `cheese` and `cheesecake` becomes `cheese cake` for instance and so on.
2. Having a dataset like:

   - `super yummy cheesecake | cheese cake`
   - `summer strawberry cake | strawberry cake`
3. Train the model to learn what matters for the topic and what is just additional information.

The way, the dataset is modeled, I have no static lables, as I understand. This makes things complicated, right?

As this is my first AI experiment with `tensorflow`, I don't really know if this will work out, or if I should go with another strategy, therefore I need your help.

Comment: One question: why a CNN? The best models to process text data are RNNs, could you elaborate more on your choice? (Not a criticism, I'm genuinely interested!)

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like not tensorflow task at all. At least not at the first place.

1. "Normalize headlines" task (lemmatization). Spacy does nice job here and it has great documentation. [Here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-pos-tagging) is an example, have a look at the "lemma" property.
2. Use the [food2vec](https://jaan.io/food2vec-augmented-cooking-machine-intelligence/) as a database of topic names.
3. Parse sentence via spacy and find the phrase in the food2vec. Parsing should be done not word-by-word, but by phrase: first look up 3-words phrase in the dictionary; if not found - 2-word dictionary; than 1 word.

This should be enough to solve your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can frame this as a sequence to sequence prediction model similar to translation and summarization. [This neural translation with attention colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb) is probably a really good place to start.